# How to make div height to be always proportional of its width (without hacks)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, percentage

I have a Flexbox `div` with 12 images within. I want `width` of every image to be `25%` of that `div`. That image must have `height` = `133,33%` of `width`. And in case image has dimensions that not equal to my 3*4, image has to be scaled to fit my 3*4. So how can I achieve that? I think I need a tool like `calc(width*4/3)`.

My css and html:

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; 
  }
  .image-grid .image-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    height: 133.3333%; // nothing happens if I delete this line. Flexbox?
    }
  .image-grid .image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-grid">
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-3.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-4.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-5.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-6.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-7.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-8.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-9.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-10.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-11.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
    <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="assets/img/portfolio-12.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

My code works perfect with images that are exactly 3*4, but if an image has other dimensions, I get that:
[image: bad image]

Ok, the solution is found. Just set wrapper's padding as 133.33% instead of height (and set my img's position as absolute). This is what I'd call a "trick" or "hack", but it solves my problem rather clearly. More details here: [description](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html#outer_wrap)

Comment: try this:
height: 100%, width: auto; *edit --> inside .image-grid .image

Comment: @PeterBejan, my images not always have the same size, so I get them stretched. I also don't have my div's height (it has to be evaluated, 4/3 of width).

Comment: @PeterBejan, and what is "*edit --> inside .image-grid .image"? CSS?

Comment: Yes, add this data inside .image-grid .image (CSS) {height: 100%; width: auto}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can maintain a 3:4 aspect-ratio on the wrapper by putting `padding-top: 133.33%`on it. 
So instead of setting the height, you can set the padding.

Also you need to set `position: relative` to the wrapper and `position: absolute` to the child, so the positioning of the child ignores the padding.

there's an example in the following snippet:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  width: 25%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 133.33%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREb_QCChITKrV0oIljZeP1irlF4UT74fQbJYNiawkZ9efEgREQoA">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Xm, I found http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html#outer_wrap that page now. Hack, but looks like it exactly what I need, and I think that is exactly what you mean, right?

Comment: if you use scss, you can use this mixin from css-tricks [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/) for a better readability and reusability

Comment: thanks for css-tricks. But... There's no "no-hack" solution, right?

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it, especially if you are using the mixin, it is a very clean and readable way. since you only have to put `@include aspect-ratio(3, 4);` on the class

Comment: Yes... Now I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-grid .image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 33.3333%;
}

.image-grid .image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-grid">
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?2.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?3.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?4.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?5.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?6.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?7.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?8.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200?9.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?2.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?4.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `padding` is a standard property, applied to a standard selector wich is parsed consistently in all major browsers in a standard way. Is it a **hack**? I don't think so..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that should work if the container spans the complete width of the window:

Make the image container 25% wide and 25vw*4/3 high (there you have your `calc`...). Also use `overflow: hidden` on the container to keep the fixed ratio.

Make the images 100% high and set their width to `auto`. This will make them fill the container vertically. Then center them by appliying `transform: translate-x(-50%)`, `position: relative` and `left: 50%;`.

This only works for images whose height is less than 4/3 of the width, but from what I understood, that's the situation you have?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-grid .image-wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(25vw*4/3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-grid .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-grid">
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-300-400-1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/transport-h-c-300-400-5.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-300-360-6.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-300-335-10.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/transport-h-c-300-400-5.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-300-360-6.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-300-335-10.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-300-400-1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>

  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-300-360-6.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-300-400-1.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/transport-h-c-300-400-5.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-300-335-10.jpg" alt="" class="image"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm looking for universal solution, so I can't get vw

Comment: What do you mean by universal? vw should cover most used browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: @Darlesson, I mean that I need a solution for any div's width, not only 100vw

Comment: If "any div's width" is a *set* width, you can calculate the height of the image container (height of image-wrapper = width of container DIV divided by 3), only if it has to be completely dynamic, this won't work. But you could use media queries with different fixed widths in various steps for that container...